# External MQTT server subscription

Tags: iot, ibm-watson, websphere

I am using IBM IoT service. Registered a device. Now i want to receive messages (this device) from external mqtt server (CloudMQTT). Please, provide detail info about the way can i subscribe to this external server.

Regards,
Mindaugas

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you are planning to subscribe: Using an app that the device came with? An app that you are going to write, if so which programming language? Node-RED?

Based on the vagueness of your question I am going to suggest that you haven't actually thought about this, in which case your best be is to use Node-RED, for which there already is a range of prebuilt IOT nodes that you can use.

Comment: In my case Lora device send messages to Actility network server. Afterwards, actility network server sends messages (got from device) to external mqtt server. I want to see these messages in IBM Watson IoT... redirect them to IBM Watson IoT.  As far as i understand - the best way is Node-RED?